# ¿Cómo desempaquetar valores de columnas específicas de un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe que representa los id y nombres de estudiantes. Quiero hacer una matriz de objetos-estudiantes. Sin embargo obtengo `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

## Mi intento:

### `main.py`

```
# main
import pandas
from student import Student

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    students_df = pandas.read_csv("students.csv")
    students = []
    print(students_df[['id','name']])
    for id,name in students_df[['id','name']]:
        print(id, name)
        students.append(Student(id,name))
        print(students)
```

### `student.py`

```
# student

class Student:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.courses=[]

    def addCourse(self,course_id):
        self.courses.append(course_id)
```

## mensaje de error.

```
(backenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Hatchways\backend-assessment>py main.py
   id name
0   1    A
1   2    B
2   3    C
i d
[<student.Student object at 0x0000014FF8C7C4A8>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    for id,name in students_df[['id','name']]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Además me parece extraño que el primero print devuelve `i d`

## Data

El archivo student.csv está [aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z6f1TLdXuqg-wItsuIVWwCsAzWWYA62r).

Answer (score 0):

¿Y te vale hacer el bucle con [iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)?

```
for _, row in students_df.iterrows():
    students.append(Student(row[0], row[1]))
```